# GraphicsMagick crashes my program on startup

Tags: macos, graphicsmagick

I just spend a few hours converting my program to use GraphicsMagick because it has some features that I'd like to use. That seems to have been a mistake. When I run my program it now crashes on:

```
Image::read
```

with this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.8. It seems like it is trying to load a shared library, but I have no idea which one and I can't find anything in the documentation that gives me any clues. Surely I'm not the first to have this problem so hopefully someone can tell me what libraries I need to include in my bundle file to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not much to go on - the arguments to the `read` method would be useful. My first thought is that you haven't initialized Magick++, e.g., [`Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/#api) prior to using the library.

It would also be useful if you could check the output of `otool -L libGraphicsMagick++.dylib` - if `libstdc++` shows up, it might cause problems with clang's `libc++`.